# Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext() in GridView item click from Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, fragment, android-tablayout

I have created android app like gallery which have some images using fragment tab

Functionality is working fine but when I add setOnItemClickListener in my code then showing error

Error : Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext()

you can also check screenshot of error : http://prntscr.com/kc6zay

Please review my code and guide me how can I solve this problem.

```
    public class CallFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call,container,false);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext())); // uses the view to get the context instead of getActivity().

        // Listening to GridView item click
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                // Launch ImageViewPager.java on selecting GridView Item
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageViewPager.class);

                // Show a simple toast message for the item position
                //Toast.makeText(CallFragment.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Send the click position to ImageViewPager.java using intent
                i.putExtra("id", position);

                // Start ImageViewPager
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }



  //  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  //                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   //     setHasOptionsMenu(true);
   //     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call, container, false);
  //  }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_calls, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_call) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is because neither `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` nor `Fragment` have such method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Add below code in `CallFragment`

```
private Context context;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
}
```

In your `onItemClick`

```
            Intent i = new Intent(context, ImageViewPager.class);
```

Comment: sorry i con't understand : Add below code in fragment

Comment: In your `CallFragment`

Comment: i try your code but when i test my app and click on itme then my app keeps stopping and saying close app

Comment: E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.codingdemos.tablayout/com.codingdemos.tablayout.ImageViewPager}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Is ImageViewPager an activity? Make sure you have added it in manifest

Comment: i have added my ImageViewPager  in manifest and it working now Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't start an activity with the `getApplicationContext`.  
Use `getActivity()`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageViewPager.class);
```

Comment: i try your code Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageViewPager.class); but when i test my app and click on itme then my app keeps stopping and saying close app

Comment: `getActivity()` can be null

Comment: `getActivity()` is null until the `onAttach()` event. After that **it is not null** and surely it is not inside a listener that it's triggered after `onAttach()`